# Why Lidar detection range in gazebo is different from setting?

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-melodic, lidar, scan

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="omo_r1_sim" xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">



 <xacro:include filename="$(find omo_r1_description)/urdf/omo_r1.urdf.xacro"/>
  <xacro:arg name="laser_visual"  default="true"/>
  <xacro:arg name="camera_visual" default="false"/>
  <xacro:arg name="imu_visual"    default="false"/>

  <gazebo reference="base_link">
    <material>Gazebo/DarkGrey</material>
  </gazebo>

  <gazebo reference="wheel_left_link">
    <mu1>1.0</mu1>
    <mu2>1.0</mu2>
    <kp>50000.0</kp>
    <kd>1.0</kd>
    <minDepth>0.001</minDepth>
    <maxVel>1.2</maxVel>
    <fdir1>1 0 0</fdir1>
    <material>Gazebo/FlatBlack</material>
  </gazebo>

  <gazebo reference="wheel_right_link">
    <mu1>1.0</mu1>
    <mu2>1.0</mu2>
    <kp>50000.0</kp>
    <kd>1.0</kd>
    <minDepth>0.001</minDepth>
    <maxVel>1.2</maxVel>
    <fdir1>1 0 0</fdir1>
    <material>Gazebo/FlatBlack</material>
  </gazebo>

  <gazebo reference="caster_back_right_link">
    <mu1>0.1</mu1>
    <mu2>0.1</mu2>
    <kp>10000.0</kp>
    <kd>10.0</kd>
    <minDepth>0.001</minDepth>
    <maxVel>1.0</maxVel>
    <material>Gazebo/FlatBlack</material>
  </gazebo>

  <gazebo reference="caster_back_left_link">
    <mu1>0.1</mu1>
    <mu2>0.1</mu2>
    <kp>10000.0</kp>
    <kd>10.0</kd>
    <minDepth>0.001</minDepth>
    <maxVel>1.0</maxVel>
    <material>Gazebo/FlatBlack</material>
  </gazebo>

  <gazebo reference="imu_link">
    <sensor type="imu" name="imu">
      <always_on>true</always_on>
      <visualize>$(arg imu_visual)</visualize>
    </sensor>
    <material>Gazebo/Grey</material>
  </gazebo>

  <gazebo>
    <plugin name="omo_r1_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so">
      <commandTopic>cmd_vel</commandTopic>
      <odometryTopic>odom</odometryTopic>
      <odometryFrame>odom</odometryFrame>
      <odometrySource>world</odometrySource>
      <publishOdomTF>true</publishOdomTF>
      <robotBaseFrame>base_footprint</robotBaseFrame>
      <publishWheelTF>false</publishWheelTF>
      <publishTf>true</publishTf>
      <publishWheelJointState>true</publishWheelJointState>
      <legacyMode>false</legacyMode>
      <updateRate>30</updateRate>
      <leftJoint>wheel_left_joint</leftJoint>
      <rightJoint>wheel_right_joint</rightJoint>
      <wheelSeparation>0.591</wheelSeparation>
      <wheelDiameter>0.220</wheelDiameter>
      <wheelAcceleration>1</wheelAcceleration>
      <wheelTorque>100</wheelTorque>
      <rosDebugLevel>na</rosDebugLevel>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>


  <gazebo>
    <plugin name="imu_plugin" filename="libgazebo_ros_imu.so">
      <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
      <bodyName>imu_link</bodyName>
      <frameName>imu_link</frameName>
      <topicName>imu</topicName>
      <serviceName>imu_service</serviceName>
      <gaussianNoise>0.0</gaussianNoise>
      <updateRate>200</updateRate>
      <imu>
        <noise>
          <type>gaussian</type>
          <rate>
            <mean>0.0</mean>
            <stddev>2e-4</stddev>
            <bias_mean>0.0000075</bias_mean>
            <bias_stddev>0.0000008</bias_stddev>
          </rate>
          <accel>
            <mean>0.0</mean>
            <stddev>1.7e-2</stddev>
            <bias_mean>0.1</bias_mean>
            <bias_stddev>0.001</bias_stddev>
          </accel>
        </noise>
      </imu>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>

  <gazebo reference="base_scan">
    <material>Gazebo/FlatBlack</material>
    <sensor type="ray" name="yd_lidar_sensor">
      <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
      <visualize>$(arg laser_visual)</visualize>
      <update_rate>10</update_rate>
      <ray>
        <scan>
          <horizontal>
            <samples>360</samples>
            <resolution>2.525</resolution> 
            <min_angle>0</min_angle>
            <max_angle>6.28319</max_angle>
          </horizontal>
        </scan>
        <range>
          <min>0.12</min>
          <max>25</max>
          <resolution>0.015</resolution>
        </range>
        
      </ray>
      <plugin name="gazebo_ros_yd_lidar_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_laser.so">
        <topicName>scan</topicName>
        <frameName>base_scan</frameName>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>
</robot>
```

*I am simulating on gazebo using omorobot r1 with ydlidar attached. Then a problem arose. This is a xacro file containing my gazebo settings. The problem is that even though the max scan range is set to 25m in the gazebo, the scan range in the gazebo is limited when it exceeds 16m in front rather than being circular, and that area is recognized as an obstacle. Although I tried a lot, I couldn't find the problem.**